# The definite article with names

Tags: articles, names

Let's suppose there is a cinema house called 'Dream'.
How to refer to it?

1. In cinema 'Dream'
2. In the cinema 'Dream'
3. In 'Dream' cinema

Or

1. In band 'Abba'
2. In the band 'Abba'
3. In 'Abba' band
4. In the 'Abba' band.

Or

With books and their titles

Or

1. at the intermediate level
2. At inter. level
3. At the level Inter
4. At level Inter.

Thanks!

Comment: All are correct, although some forms will require the use of comma before and after the name

Comment: If all are correct, are there any rules to understand how and why they are correct and what to choose? And when do we need to use commas?

Comment: You can choose any one of them, comma will be used if the sentence is continuing. E.g  In the cinema Dream, no movies were being displayed.

Comment: It is better to use the sentences with "the" article, although its not necessary

Answer (score -1):

The post ***"The definite article*" with names*** is a little confusing.

***Using the definite article*** with books and their titles

In this case we only need to use the definite article to specify something. Lets show a couple of examples of the use or not of the definite article

In **the film** Treasure Island by Eric Bigonof  set in the 23rd century. *Here the definite article is used to refer to a specific in this case a  film. * **Film** is a general term for something but here we are linking it with a name to make a reference to something of which only one exists at any one time.

High school students are advised to read Treasure Island. *In this case the definite article is not needed.* The name is already used to refer to something unique.

**Names of holidays, countries, companies, languages, etc. are all proper nouns. You don’t need to use an article with a proper noun.
Geography
Articles are not used before countries (unless the names include words like kingdom, states or republic), states, cities, towns, continents, single lakes, or single mountains.
The following are also examples of when we do not need use the definite article.
Companies
Universities unless it's name starts with Uninverity (The University of Toront)
Languages
Places, locations, streets (if they are specific)
Sports
Subjects you study at school
Noun+number (room 12)
Acronyms unless the letters are pronounced individually, not as a word (UN)**

```
***In the examples posted why are we using the definite article?***
```

***we using the definite article*** to refer to things or people when only one exists at any one time: [CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/the)

After I leave college, I want to travel around ***the world***.

Ed Koch was for many years ***the mayor of New York***.

When we went to Paris, we went up ***the Eiffel Tower***.

***or are we using the definite article*** before superlatives and other words, such as "first" or "only" or numbers showing something's position in a list, to refer to only one thing or person:

`In the examples given I would suggest that the only really valid one is`

"at the intermediate level" (*position in a list*)

**Finally are we mixing the uses of the definite article?** In this case **are we using the definite article to create or define a name?** or a we **using it because we have already mentioned it?**

```
In this example 

*let's say the documentation needs to mention that some program named show_password is required. Then we can put it in the following ways: 
 
a) "requires show_password" (no article, the program is called by its name) 

b) "requires the show_password program"*
```

**In this case what is happening?** The answer is we are mixing the uses of the word "The" whilst building our example.

Whilst in answer b) we are just using the definite article to show something is specific.

In answer a) we have dropped "the definite article" ???

Here is a correct example. [British council](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/english-grammar-reference/definite-article)

A young **man** got a nasty shock when he tried to rob a jewellery shop in Richmond. The **man** used a heavy hammer to smash the windows in the shop.

we have dropped young (because we have already mentioned it and replaced it with "the") but man still remains in use

so we should have an example like this

a) "requires a program called show_password" (no article, the program is called by its name).

b)  "requires the program" (we have dropped the name, because we have already mentioned it and replaced it with "the")

Comment: Thanks. But  why is it that we can use 'at the Dream cinema', but not 'in the ABBA band'? In the 'in the band ABBA' the defines band, and ABBA is just the name of the band. But in 'at the Dream cinema', when it is Dream, not 'The Dream', can't Dream be understood as a premodifying  word for cinema? If not, as it is a noun, not an adj., it's supposed to be ok to say 'in the ABBA band'.

Comment: The problem with "Band" is that it has other meanings. Rubber Band, Bandwidth etc.

Comment: If you use the form The Band ABBA native speakers will know you are talking about a Pop group. Whilst if you put the Band last then what you mean is ABBA (the) Band (even though you do not write the) as opposed to the Band ABBA, this may be misconstrued that you are talking about another form of Band, not a Pop group. This Band having the name ABBA. It is an arguable point. I would be surprised if non native speakers would pick up on this. I am not sure what Americans  would do . But I would not use "ABBA Band

Comment: So, when we use the name before the category, does this name act as a pre modifyer, and can it be interpreted as smth characterizing the following word. It feels like in 'the Dream cinema' we can read it as 'at the dream cinema', and, accordingly, understand it like 'the cinema of one' s dream'. And 'in Abba band' can be understood like 'band of Abba members' (where 'band' is just a group of people, not 'mus.band). If so, how to distinguish between these two concepts? Only noticing the capital letters?

Comment: @Brad, could you please help a bit with the slightly modified example: let's say the documentation needs to mention that some program named `show_password` is required. Then we can put it in the following ways: a) **"requires `show_password`"** (no article, the program is called by its name) b) **"requires the `show_password` program"** ('the' article because it *sort of* relates to the category 'program', like in "the ABBA group"?), is this correct?

Comment: You seem to have missed the point. I have rewritten my answer I hope this makes things clear